# Trigonometric equation without graphs

Tags: trigonometry

$$\cos a-\sin a\ge0,\ a\in[0,2\pi]$$
$\cot a\ge1$. After this I am unable to proceed, is there a method to calculate the answer without drawing a graph?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$\frac{\sqrt 2}{2}\cos a-\frac{\sqrt 2}{2}\sin a\ge 0$$
$$\cos a\cos\frac{\pi}{4}-\sin a\sin\frac{\pi}{4}\ge 0$$
$$\cos(a+\frac{\pi}{4})\ge 0$$

Call $b=a+\frac{\pi}{4}$, then $b\in[\frac{\pi}{4}, 2\pi+\frac{\pi}{4}]$ and $\cos b\ge 0$ for $b\in[\frac{\pi}{4}, \frac{\pi}{2}]\cup[\frac{3\pi}{2},2\pi+\frac{\pi}{4}]$. Then, $a\in[0,\frac{\pi}{4}]\cup[\frac{5\pi}{4}, 2\pi]$.

Comment: nice i got it thanks a ton !!

Comment: sorry to pin you again @user8734617   what you did after cos b >=0 ??

Comment: @sumitgoyal Just got back from $b$ to $a$, using $a=b-\frac{\pi}{4}$, i.e. I translated all those intervals back by $\frac{\pi}{4}$.

Comment: no thats fine iam asking  about  (pie)/2  where it come from

Comment: please tell   ...

Comment: @sumitgoyal Just knowing the ordinary trigonometry, i.e. when $\cos b\ge 0$. I don't need to draw graphs for that, I know $\cos b\ge 0$ in the first and fourth quadrant, i.e. angles $0..\frac{\pi}{2}$ and $\frac{3\pi}{2}..2\pi$ and further on: $2\pi..2\pi+\frac{\pi}{2}$ etc.

Comment: now i got it thnkuu

Answer (score 1):

$$\cos a-\sin a=\sqrt2\left(\frac1{\sqrt2}\cos a-\frac1{\sqrt2}\sin a\right)=$$
$$==\sqrt2\left(\cos\frac{\pi}4\cos a-\sin\frac{\pi}4\sin a\right)=\sqrt2\cos \left(a+\frac{\pi}4\right)$$

Comment: thanku sir for replying  , answer should be in intervals   isnt it  ?

Comment: @sumitgoyal  This transformation helps you solve for those intervals.

Comment: nice i got it thanks a ton !!

Answer (score 0):

$$a\in(0,\pi)\implies\sin a>0$$ allows you to write $$\cot a\ge1$$ or $$a\ge\text{arccot }1=\frac\pi4.$$

Similarly,

$$a\in(\pi,2\pi)\implies\sin a<0$$ allows you to write $$\cot a\le1$$ or $$a\le\pi+\text{arccot }1=\frac{3\pi}4.$$

Hence, adding the values at endpoints of the intervals,

$$\left[\frac\pi4,\frac{3\pi}4\right].$$